# How to create a new project with activator for Lagom

Tags: sbt, typesafe-activator, lagom

Just downloaded and installed the last version of the `activator` (1.3.10) following [this guide](http://www.lagomframework.com/documentation/1.2.x/java/Installation.html).

The location where I installed the `activator` distro is writable and `activator-1.3.10/bin` was added to my `$PATH`.

Then, I tried to create a new project like this:

```
activator new test-project lagom-scala
```

... but I always get the following errors:

```
j3d@gonzo:~/Projects$ activator new test-project lagom-scala
Getting com.typesafe.activator activator-launcher 1.3.10 ...

:: problems summary ::
:::: WARNINGS
    module not found: com.typesafe.activator#activator-launcher;1.3.10

    ==== local: tried

      /home/j3d/.ivy2/local/com.typesafe.activator/activator-launcher/1.3.10/ivys/ivy.xml

      -- artifact com.typesafe.activator#activator-launcher;1.3.10!activator-launcher.jar:

      /home/j3d/.ivy2/local/com.typesafe.activator/activator-launcher/1.3.10/jars/activator-launcher.jar

    ==== activator-launcher-local: tried

    file:/opt/activator-1.3.10-minimal/repository/com.typesafe.activator/activator-launcher/1.3.10/ivys/ivy.xml

    ==== Maven Central: tried

      https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/typesafe/activator/activator-launcher/1.3.10/activator-launcher-1.3.10.pom

      -- artifact com.typesafe.activator#activator-launcher;1.3.10!activator-launcher.jar:

      https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/typesafe/activator/activator-launcher/1.3.10/activator-launcher-1.3.10.jar

    ==== typesafe-releases: tried

  https://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/releases/com/typesafe/activator/activator-launcher/1.3.10/activator-launcher-1.3.10.pom

      -- artifact com.typesafe.activator#activator-launcher;1.3.10!activator-launcher.jar:

  https://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/releases/com/typesafe/activator/activator-launcher/1.3.10/activator-launcher-1.3.10.jar

    ==== typesafe-ivy-releasez: tried

  https://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/ivy-releases/com.typesafe.activator/activator-launcher/1.3.10/ivys/ivy.xml

        ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::

        ::          UNRESOLVED DEPENDENCIES         ::

        ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::

        :: com.typesafe.activator#activator-launcher;1.3.10: not found

        ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::


:::: ERRORS
    Server access Error: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unexpected error: java.security.InvalidAlgorithmParameterException: the trustAnchors parameter must be non-empty url=https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/typesafe/activator/activator-launcher/1.3.10/activator-launcher-1.3.10.pom

    Server access Error: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unexpected error: java.security.InvalidAlgorithmParameterException: the trustAnchors parameter must be non-empty url=https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/typesafe/activator/activator-launcher/1.3.10/activator-launcher-1.3.10.jar

    Server access Error: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unexpected error: java.security.InvalidAlgorithmParameterException: the trustAnchors parameter must be non-empty url=https://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/releases/com/typesafe/activator/activator-launcher/1.3.10/activator-launcher-1.3.10.pom

    Server access Error: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unexpected error: java.security.InvalidAlgorithmParameterException: the trustAnchors parameter must be non-empty url=https://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/releases/com/typesafe/activator/activator-launcher/1.3.10/activator-launcher-1.3.10.jar

    Server access Error: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unexpected error: java.security.InvalidAlgorithmParameterException: the trustAnchors parameter must be non-empty url=https://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/ivy-releases/com.typesafe.activator/activator-launcher/1.3.10/ivys/ivy.xml


:: USE VERBOSE OR DEBUG MESSAGE LEVEL FOR MORE DETAILS
unresolved dependency: com.typesafe.activator#activator-launcher;1.3.10: not found
Error during sbt execution: Error retrieving required libraries
  (see /home/j3d/.sbt/boot/update.log for complete log)
Error: Could not retrieve activator-launcher 1.3.10
```

Any help would be really appreciaded.

Answer (score 0):

Googling further I've found there is an issue on Ubuntu that can be solved as described [here](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/ca-certificates-java/+bug/1396760). I hope it helps.